# Mean energy of an arbitrary eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, wavefunction

> It is known that a particle has the following eigenfunction
>   $$\psi(x,y,z) = N(x-y+z)e^{-ar}$$
>   where $N$ is the normalization constant, $a>0$ and $r=\sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$. Find the the average energy and the function which depends of time.

First, we calculate the normalization constant:

$$N^2 \int r^4[\sin\theta(\cos\phi - \sin\phi)]^2e^{-2ar}dr^3 = 1   \longrightarrow N = \sqrt\frac{a^5}{3\pi} \, ,$$

where I assumed that the eigenfunction describes a free particle (which seems odd because it doesn't have the form of a wavepacket, but then what boundaries should one assume?). Now, I'm bit confused about how to calculate the average energy. I was thinking of obtaining the mean value of the Hamiltonian $\langle \psi|\hat{H}|\psi \rangle$, but probably is doesn't represent the average energy.

Furthermore, I was wondering if just applying the time evolution operator $\hat{U}$ to the eigenfunction would spit out the form of $\psi(x,y,z,t)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you don't care if the particle is free or not when calculating the normalization constant. You just integrate the square of the wavefunction.

Second, the average energy is by definition the mean value of the Hamiltonian so yes, that's what you should do. You do need to know the Hamiltonian, though. If I had to guess, I'd say that this looks very much like a bound state of hydrogen, but without more information we can't know for sure.

Lastly yes, applying the evolution operator does give the time-dependent wavefunction, but applying the evolution operator is just equivalent to solving the Schrödinger equation. What you do in these cases is expand your initial wavefunction as a superposition of the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian (for which, again, you need to know the Hamiltonian) and evolve each term with a factor $e^{-iEt/\hbar}$, using the corresponding energy $E$ for each state. The specific details depend on the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Well, the problem states no information about the Hamiltonian, that's a bit problematic. Thanks for your remarks.

Comment: @Cifer in that case the problem is ill-posed. Most likely you're supposed to know what $H$ is from context; in this case, it's almost surely either a free particle or a hydrogen atom.

Comment: I also would like to know the reason behind the downvote, so I can improve my answer.

Comment: Hi Javier, as a new user it seems I can't upvote nor downvote. Your answer was quite helpful.